# How to pass String paramaters in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

Below code is an output.jsp to display the data submitted from submit.jsp in a  format. I am fairly new to JSP and would like some guidance in how to pass paramaters firstname/lastname into html tags. Please advise . I have tried couple of approcahes with no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h>The first and last name are</h>
<%
String firstname = (String) request.getAttribute("firstname");
String lastname  = (String) request.getAttribute("lastname");

//out.println(firstname  + "                     " + lastname);
%>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name : </td><td><% firstname  %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name : </td><td><% lastname %></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error that are thrown when running output.jsp.

```
An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /output.jsp
firstname cannot be resolved to a type
17: %>
18: <table>
19: <tr>
20: <td>First Name : </td><td><% firstname  %></td>
21: </tr>
22: <tr>
23: <td>Last Name : </td><td><% lastname %></td>


An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /output.jsp
lastname cannot be resolved to a type
20: <td>First Name : </td><td><% firstname  %></td>
21: </tr>
22: <tr>
23: <td>Last Name : </td><td><% lastname %></td>
24: </tr>
25: </table>
26: </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `<td><% firstname  %></td>` and `<td><% lastname  %></td>` 
try `<td><%= firstname  %></td>` and `<td><%= lastname  %></td>`

Comment: Thanks, this was not suggested anywhere as missing = operator . Yes, it worked. Thanks @gefei

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you're using an invalid scriptlet, they should be avoided

Try using [el](/questions/tagged/el) instead

```
<td>${firstname}</td>
```

Related: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

Comment: thanks @Reimeus, while exploring jsp I came across EL as an option,but was not sure.... as I am trying to better my skill-set will def look into this.